# Magento missing a lot of catalog images after migration

Tags: php, mysql, magento, image-processing, magento-1.6

I recently moved a magento installation to a new server.

All went fine, I got a new beast to run my ecommerce very quickly, but unfortunatly I noticed that tons of images are missing...
Some are there and some are not... what can be gone wrong? I rsynced the media directories, it seems to me that the new location is trying to find them under another media/catalog path...

How can I fix it? Actually I'm doing it by hand re-uploading images, but this is not a quick solution.

Answer (score 2):

Not enough information to locate the problem.

1) But in most cases problem is in folder and file names. 
If you copy files from windows pc, you lose some files.

Example:

- /media/catalog/product/D/DSC.jpg
- /media/catalog/product/d/dsc001.jpg

both files will be in D or d folder, not in both.

2) Second possibility

For some reasons original files on your old server were lost, but cache files are available - so visually website is fine.

3) Third possibility

You don't have enough permissions for some media files to copy them.

Comment: I've seen the first issue plenty of times, due to windows being case insensitive - I would guess this is the problem :-)

Comment: Fortunatly I don't work with Windows machines, only linux and mac here :-))

Comment: Both servers are linux, so I don't think some file is missing because of naming... I moved the DB and the media directory, i didn't use the "import" option to import the catalog (dumped and restore the db on the new db).

The cache on the old server was disabled and the new media is 777.

Comment: Try to find out one missing image problem (get it path in database and try to find it on hdd. If it does not exist - try to find it on old server or in near folders on new server). After this you will get more info about problem.